# Store Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise credentials private_key in Azure Static Web Apps Configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-functions, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app, recaptcha-enterprise

I have developed Azure Static Web Apps (Blazor Webassembly, Visual Studio 2022 Community) with integrated Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise service. Handling reCAPTCHA Enterprise is done in Azure Functions, which also sends an e-mail (using Sendgrid).
During development, I stored my Google credentials in the `local.settings.json` file.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "SendGridApiKey": "<my Sendgrid key>",
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "<my project_id>",
    "private_key_id": "<my private_key_id>",
    "private_key": "<my private_key>",
    "client_email": "my client_email",
    "client_id": "<my client_id>",
    "auth_uri": "<auth_uri>",
    "token_uri": "<token_uri>",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "<auth_provider_x509_cert_url>",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "<client_x509_cert_url>",
    "universe_domain": "googleapis.com",
    "site_key": "<site_key>"
  },
  "Host": { "CORS": "*" }
}
```

The `private_key` contains 1733 characters, starts with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n`, ends with `\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`, and has a lot of escape characters and slashes, back-slashes as well `\n`, `/\n`, `\`, `/`.

During development, everything works fine! But unfortunately NOT in production.

If I store the `private_key` in the App configuration area, my Google Service will fail authentication. The only way I managed to get it working was to store `private_key` as a `string` in my code. All the rest is stored in the App configuration.

I'm sure that the problem arises because of the `\n`, but I have no idea how to handle that in the configuration value pairs.

Any idea how to manage this?

Comment: can you work with the json by NewtonSoft lib ?

Comment: I've already bound `using Newtonsoft.Json` and `using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters` in my code